# Compress multiple HTML pages using tree encoding

Tags: python, html, encoding, compression, huffman-code

I noticed that Huffman Coding can be used to compress strings by creating a tree.

But I was wondering.. could this also be applied to HTML pages?

Imagine you want to compress a whole domain, or pages over time. A lot of nodes will be repeating over time (as pages don't change), and a lot of pages contain overlapping nodes. At different heights in their trees.

```
<div>
   menu
   <ul>
      <li>some</li>
      <li>some</li>
      <li>another</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The example HTML can perhaps create an element out of each HTML node (the `<li>some</li>` occuring twice), perhaps the whole `<ul>` could be expressed as a single element, or perhaps it even pays off to encode this whole text as a single element if there are more pages that contain this exactly.

So I was wondering how can Huffman Coding be applied to this problem?

Comment: You wouldn't just use a variable length code on its own, you'd add some modelling or transformation stages before it. Say, some dictionary based scheme (to transform longer repeated sequences -- such as tags, or even whole lines like in your example -- into shorter symbols), and then code Huffman code (or use some other variable length encoding scheme) its output (like DEFLATE does).

Comment: @DanMašek Right - some way to combine nodes if the result will be smaller than encoding the elements below separately. I'll have a look at DEFLATE.